# Why does accessing globals work via import module, but not from module import var?

Tags: python, import, module, global

I've been reading and learning a ton about python, but all the import variations having different results is a tad confusing.

I was having an issue where a global variable I had imported was always the default value, even though I called a method in that module that manipulates it. I had imported it like so:

```
from fona import connect, disconnect, CON
```

Where the first two are functions and the last the var. The first two either open or close the connection, to which I have access via the var CON. When I did it this way, CON would stay None, even though connect is initializing it successfully (I have a lot of verbose output to verify that). I messed around more and more and couldn't figure it out. Wrote a post very different to this one before I had one more idea.

```
import fona
```

I then access everything via fona.connect/disco/CON. Then it works. I am struggling to fathom why and couldn't find any resources. What makes these imports different? I quite like `from x import y as z`, but it seems I cannot use that in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, "global" means "module-level" (actually at runtime a "global" variable is an attribute of the `module` object instance).

Now this statement:

```
from fona import CON
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```
import fona
CON = fona.CON 
del fona
```

so at this point we have two names pointing at the same object - `fon.CON` and `<yourothermodule>.CON`

Now if in `fona` we have a function that rebinds `fona.CON`, ie:

```
def foo():
    global CON
    con = "XXX"
```

calling this function will ONLY rebind `fona.CON`, not the `CON` variable in `<yourothermodule>`.

If instead in  you import the whole `fona` module and use `fona.CON` you do see the effects of the rebiding after calling `fona.foo()` because you are actually accessing the `fona` module's attribute, not your local (local to ) attribute.

Actually you would have the very same situation with two dicts in the same  module:

```
d1 = {"a":1}
d2 = {}
d2["a"] = d1["a"]
d1["a"] = 42 # this won't change d2["a"]
print d1, d2
```

In fact you don't even need dicts, just two names in the same namespace are enough:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> print a
1
>>> print b
1
>>> b is a
True
```

As you can see, at this point `b` is not a 'copy' of `a`, it's really just another name bound to the very same object. Now if we rebind `a`:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> print a
2
>>> print b
1
>>> b is a
False
>>>
```

we can see that it doesn't affect `b`, it only makes `a` point to another object.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had incorrectly assumed that it would be a reference to that variable instead of another instance/copy.

Comment: It **is** a reference - Python never copies anything unless explicitely asked for. But when you **rebind**  `fona.CON` it doesn't change other bindings to what `fona.CON` was previously bound to - cf the dict example in my answer. If you use a mutable object instead and mutate it instead of rebinding the name to another object you will find that both names DO point to the same object (until one of the names is rebound of course).

Comment: OK, it makes a lot more sense now. I had a falsely assumed doing 'from fona import CON' would give me the reference to CON, so that when CON is altered in the fona module (via connect/disco), CON would be up to date in my module. However a "local" is created that is a reference to what CON was at import and as CON(fona)gets reassigned, it does not. Calling fona.CON however, checks the fona module.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
from fona import CON
```

is pretty much the same* as:

```
import fona
CON = fona.CON
```

Now, if `fona` changes internally so that `fona.CON` is replaced with a new value, this has no effect on your own variable. Just like if you say:

```
y = 1
x = y
y = 2
```

`x` is still 1 even though `y` is now 2.

---

<sup>*except the latter leaves the name `fona` hanging around, the former does not.</sup>